# javascript function freezing my browser

Tags: javascript, html

i have two select object one with begining time and one with ending time.
when i select for example 11:00 in begining time i want that all options before 11:00 in ending time bee disabled 11:15 selected and rest options selectable.
Also i want to say that i am newbie with javascript.

This is part of my HTML code:

```
<select id="rbaslasaat" onchange="bitissaati(1384581600, 1384586100);">
<option value="1384581600">10:00</option>
<option value="1384582500">10:30</option>
<option value="1384583400">11:00</option>
<option value="1384584300">11:30</option>
<option value="1384585200">12:00</option>
<option value="1384586100">12:30</option>
</select></div>

<select id="rbitirsaat">
<option id="saatb1384581600" value="1384581600" disabled="">10:00</option>
<option id="saatb1384582500" value="1384582500" disabled="">10:30</option>
<option id="saatb1384583400" value="1384583400" disabled="">11:00</option>
<option id="saatb1384584300" value="1384584300" disabled="">11:30</option>
<option id="saatb1384585200" value="1384585200" disabled="">12:00</option>
<option id="saatb1384586100" value="1384586100" disabled="">12:30</option>
</select></div>
```

and this is my JavaScript function:

```
function bitissaati(saata, saatb) {
var saata, saatb, saatc, saatca, sec, i;
saatc = document.getElementById('rbaslasaat');
saatca = saatc.options[saatc.selectedIndex].value;
sec = parseInt(saatca) + 900;
for (i = saata; i<= saatb; i + 900) {
if(i <= saatca ) { document.getElementById('saatb'+i).disabled=true; }
else { document.getElementById('saatb'+i).disabled=false; }
}
document.getElementById('saatb'+sec).selected=true;
}
```

i could not figured out what the problem is.
each time i try function my browser is freezing.

Thank you all for trying to help

Comment: You override the function arguments within `var`, they'll become `undefined`.

Comment: Seems like simple debugging would be enough to understand the program's flow. Play computer, either single-step in a debugger, or use pencil and paper. What are the values, and when?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get your code fixed:

```
for ( i = saata; i<= saatb; i += 900) {
```

edit: removed the `var`

Comment: How does that fix it, `i` is defined at the top ?

Comment: this is solving my problem for freezing. but now i have another error cannot set property disabled of null

Comment: also i want to ask why i need to define var i again when i have it defined above on the begining of the function?

Answer (score 2):

I'd just do :

```
function bitissaati(elem) {
    var opt = document.getElementById('rbitirsaat').getElementsByTagName('option'),
        val = elem.value;

    for (i=opt.length; i--;)  {
        opt[i].disabled = opt[i].value <= val;
    }
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/UG26F/1/)

Comment: this works. but i just want to ask one more thing. what exactly opt[i].disabled = opt[i].value <= val; is doing ??

Comment: opt[i] is the currently iterated option, and `opt[i].disabled = true/false` sets the disabled property to true or false, so comparing the value of the selected option in the previous select to the value of the currently iterated option returns false if the current option has a time value less then or equal to the one selected in the previous select, thus setting the disabled property to true or false.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `loop` with this

```
for (var k = saata; k<= saatb; k += 900) {
    if (k <= saatca) {
        document.getElementById('saatb'+k).disabled=true;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('saatb'+k).disabled=false;
    }
}
```

Comment: So, it doesn't matter at all, that `saata` and `saatb` are `undefined`?